# curl (56) Recv failure

Tags: curl, recv

While running the command:

`curl --head http://www.yourdomain.com/`

on my local machine, I get this output:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Sat, 31 Mar 2012 09:45:16 GMT

Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727

Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=p2mt4l553bti4x55geyiwiil; path=/; HttpOnly

Cache-Control: private

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 14663`

but on my live server, I just get:

`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

They are both using the same curl version (7.21.0) and for now, I am only getting this error for only one specific url.

How should I fix this?

Comment: firewall issue? probably has nothing to do with curl...

Answer (score 1):

"Recv failure" means a recv() call failed within libcurl, which then indicates a network problem of some sorts. It is hard to be very specific on what you should do to track this down but wiresharking the network to see exactly what happens on TCP level would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

copied from [CURL ERROR: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer - PHP Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285700/curl-error-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-php-curl#)

I think the section D,E might help:

D. Maximum Transmission Unit

One common cause of this error is that the MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) size of packets travelling over your network connection have been changed from the default of 1500 bytes. If you have configured VPN this most likely must changed during configuration

D. Firewall : iptables

If you don't know your way around this guys they would cause some serious issues .. try and access the server you are connecting to check the following

You have access to port 80 on that server
Example

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`
The Following is at the last line not before any other ACCEPT
Example

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
Check for ALL DROP , REJECT and make sure they are not blocking your connection

Temporary allow all connection as see if it foes through