# Service Unavailable Using 2 CURL calls to different URL -- PHP

Tags: php, curl, internal-server-error

HERE is my CURL CODE :

```
function get_curl_data($urlToHit) {
    $ch = curl_init($urlToHit);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

I call the above function twice in same php page with 2 different URL on different HOST. When I do so, I get Service Unavailable -- With internal server error -- The error log has segmentation fault error.

But When I just make 1 Curl Call using any of the 2 URL , the code works fine.

Why isn't it allowing me to make 2 curl calls in same page ?

Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

I just add the curl option"FOLLOWLOCATION" and it works great for me, look below:

```
    function get_curl_data($urlToHit) {
        $ch = curl_init($urlToHit);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    get_curl_data('http://google.com');
    get_curl_data('http://register.com');
    get_curl_data('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, Thanks for reply

I tried the solution you gave, But that didn't work for me. 
I also tried `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`
Still getting the same error.

Is it that I make 2 curl calls on same page and there would some header conflict with 2 HTTP request on 2 diff HOST ? 

Any idea why does segmentation fault occurs giving internal server error ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been resolved after I upgraded the PHP from PHP 5.3.3 to PHP 5.4.34 . 
PHP 5.3.3 has some bugs related to CURL : [CURL ERROR: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer - PHP Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285700/curl-error-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-php-curl)