# Curl multi request error: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: php, curl, centos

Before explaining my issues I already read this article but I think is not my case:

[CURL ERROR: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer - PHP Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285700/curl-error-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-php-curl)

I have 2 servers, both centos 7.4

On the first server I create a curl multi request in a php file with 1000 , make the request to another php file in the second server and then sleep for 20 seconds.

On the second server everything executes properly, the php script executes almost 1000 times.

However, if I increase the request to be more than 1000, I receive this error in my error_log on the main server:

```
Curl error on handle : Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I am pretty sure there is a limit in any or both servers

This is the output of "sysctl -a | grep netfilter" in the second server

```
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.em1.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.p4p1.stable_secret"
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets = 65536
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_checksum = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 359
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_loose = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_closereq = 64
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_closing = 64
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_open = 43200
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_partopen = 480
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_request = 240
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_respond = 480
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_timewait = 240
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_events = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_events_retry_timeout = 15
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_expect_max = 1024
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_frag6_high_thresh = 4194304
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_frag6_low_thresh = 3145728
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_frag6_timeout = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 600
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmpv6_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_log_invalid = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 65536
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_closed = 10
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_cookie_echoed = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_cookie_wait = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_established = 432000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_heartbeat_acked = 210
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_heartbeat_sent = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_shutdown_ack_sent = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_shutdown_recd = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_shutdown_sent = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_max_retrans = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 600
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 90
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_timestamp = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 180
net.netfilter.nf_log.0 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.1 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.10 = nf_log_ipv6
net.netfilter.nf_log.11 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.12 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.2 = nf_log_ipv4
net.netfilter.nf_log.3 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.4 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.5 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.6 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.7 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.8 = NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.9 = NONE
```

What limit or limits should I tweak in any or both servers in order to allow infinite TCP connections or HTTP requests between both servers?

I would appreciate any help.