# Is this the correct way to use CURL (via PHP) to issue requests with a proxy?

Tags: php, curl

Is this the correct way to use CURL (via PHP) to issue requests with a proxy?

```
$url ="https://www.website.com";
$ch = curl_init($url);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "Proxy:Port");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: The option for the `HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` is not necessary in this case if you just  simply want to curl through proxy server... And yes you are right and try to give it a go...

Comment: Btw it is better to put one more option which is `FOLLOWLOCATION` and set it to true just in case there are internal redirect action on the target curl location

Comment: Lisbeth. Thank you

Comment: see guzzle and then `$client->request('GET', '/', ['proxy' => 'tcp://localhost:8125']);`

Comment: @gitguddoge, I add some test: $loadtime = time(); $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch); echo "cURL time: " . (time() - $loadtime) . "s<br />\
"; if ($response === false) {
    echo "cURL Error: ", curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $response;
} //obtain: cURL time: 1s
\ cURL Error: TCP connection reset by peer

Comment: Robert, I have no access to server to install guzzle

Comment: Honestly I never encounter this error before but you may take a look at this [curl error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285700/curl-error-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-php-curl)

Comment: @gitguddoge I saw this page before, but my IT told me that the problem with my code, and no problem in Firewall or server enable options in this case, is it possible?

Comment: For me I would check up for the possible validation upon the target request site such as necessary headers, post fields, or other information... try to execute and observe the response data using `curl_exec` in the network tab rather than using `curl_getinfo`... Hope this helps

Comment: I tried to check with curl_getinfo as I mentioned in previous reply, and I obtain:  cURL Error: TCP connection reset by peer. Also I tested my request to same webpage without proxy from another web server and it is ok.

Comment: Is exist any way to check if proxy settings allowed me to access threw?

Comment: I tested the proxy via browser it is work, can be any reason to Firewall bloking the CURL GET reguest?