# Getting error curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, curl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I know this error has been posted before on StackOverflow and many solutions/answers are available too. But, I've already gone through all those answers and couldn't find any viable solution for me.

I'm running a Hyperledger Fabric network with single peer and orderer. Their Docker containers have exposed the following ports. `7051:7051` & `7053:7053` on peer, `7050:7050` on orderer. I'm trying to configure Prometheus to analyse the metrics by following the official [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_service.html#) .

As mentioned in the documentation, I'm exposing my local machine's `9443` port to port `9443` of peer docker container by mapping it as `9443:9443` in `ports` section of `docker-compose.yaml`. When I run `curl 0.0.0.0:9443`, I get `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` error.

However, when I run the command `curl 0.0.0.0:9443/logspec` in my peer container I get the desired result which is `{"spec":"info"}`. The two commands mentioned above are different but I've also tried running the command `curl 0.0.0.0:9443/logspec` in my local machine to which I got the same error response.

Running the command `curl -v 0.0.0.0:9443` results in following response.

```
* About to connect() to 0.0.0.0 port 9443 (#0)
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0) port 9443 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 0.0.0.0:9443
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I read in many of the answers that I might be a firewall issue. But even after disabling my firewall using the command `systemctl disable firewalld`, it's not working.

`cat etc/os-release` response

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

`curl --version` response

```
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.34 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
```

I request you not to mark this question as duplicate as I've already gone through all the possible scenarios mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349895/6352772).

Answer (score 1):

First of all please check if there is firewall. Disable it.
Then remove the IP address provided in `core.yaml` file in operations tab. So that line will look like a below:

```
operations:
    # host and port for the operations server
    listenAddress: :9443
```

This change worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didn't have to disable my firewall though.

Comment: Changing listenAddress: :9443 to listenAddress: 0.0.0.0:9443 also worked.