# HTTPS requests to paypal sandbox fail

Tags: ssl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I can't currently use the PayPal Sandbox to test my shopping-cart integrations. When i access the sandbox in a browser or via curl, all i get is connection errors.

Here's an example curl-session:

```
curl -v "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?user=test"
*   Trying 173.0.82.83...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.83) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
* Server certificate: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> GET /nvp?user=test HTTP/1.1
> Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* SSLRead() return error -9806
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
```

Any hints if this is a serverside issue or something i can work around?

Thanks!

Comment: **Update**: I solved this issue by using POST instead of GET, when talking to the sandbox. Go figure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly understand why, but using POST instead of GET when submitting data to the PayPal Sandbox solves the problem nicely. No more weird SSL-errors.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the NVP/SOAP integration method of Paypal Express Checkout is [deprecated as of January 1, 2017](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ec_initiate_payment).  The live URL (https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp) seems to work for now, but this might be why the sandbox doesn't work anymore.

Comment: That's probably it. Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 0):

Found below answer to curl 56 error . Hope that could help work out of the problem.

[curl (56) Recv failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954877/curl-56-recv-failure)

[PHP CURL Error - curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500847/php-curl-error-curl-56-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer)

Comment: Thanks! I also get a different error message, when accessing the URL in a Webbrowser, so this is not a curl-only-problem.